# python os.environ['SECRET_NAME'] cannot get value "SECRET_VALUE" from aws codebuild ecr container

Tags: python-3.x, environment-variables, containers, aws-codebuild

> How can python get all os env?

my python script cannot get all env variable inside running ubuntu 16 container in aws codebuild

```
for item, value in os.environ.items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(item, value))
```

These are env variables that python script got:

```
SUDO_UID: 0
USER: root
HOME: /root
SUDO_USER: root
PATH: 
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
SUDO_COMMAND: /usr/bin/python3 get-env.py
SHELL: /bin/bash
USERNAME: root
TERM: xterm
LANG: C.UTF-8
HOSTNAME: 53f187197b9e
LC_ALL: C.UTF-8
MAIL: /var/mail/root
LOGNAME: root
```

and these are a part of env variables that command **printenv** got:

```
MAVEN_OPTS=-Dmaven.wagon.httpconnectionManager.maxPerRoute=2
CODEBUILD_LAST_EXIT=0
CODEBUILD_START_TIME=1552450745205
CODEBUILD_AGENT_ENDPOINT=http://127.0.0.1:7831
HOSTNAME=53f187197b9e
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
AWS_EXECUTION_ENV=AWS_ECS_EC2
FPM_MAX_CHILDREN=32
NGINX_LOG_PATH=/var/log/nginx
COMPOSER_HOME=/root/composer
VERSION=0.7.0
COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
TERM=xterm
FPM_MAX_REQUEST=1024
.....
```

I tried to use **export** command, but it didn't work

Comment: This has nothing to do with python. Python has no difficulty enumerating all env vars it inherited. There is a difference between how you are running your python program and the printenv command. Please update your question to show how your are running each program. The fact your python env output shows `SUDO_` vars and the printenv output does not implies you are launching the python program, but not printenv, via `sudo`.

Comment: I put getenv.py in a folder named /Script and run both **python3 getenv.py** and **sudo python3 getenv.py**. But, it didn't work for both

Comment: In the same shell type `printenv` then `python3 getenv.py`. They should show the same data. What do you observe? Note that `sudo` by default discards most env vars for security. So if you are not seeing the expected env vars when you run `sudo python3 getenv.py` that is expected behavior and has nothing to do with python.

Comment: I got it. you're right, there is no problem with python. It cannot print variable which is in secure but still can use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it! because some environment variables are in secure, so python cannot print them directly, but still use them.

We can see it in bitbucket pipeline variable example.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVwkT4oHDd8

Answer (score 0):

If you have variables in a file say `file.sh` you can try exporting by `. file.sh`
or bettter you can try [dotenv](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv) works well

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if this is the result of running a command with sudo based on the environment variables you are showing.

if so, have you tried running it with `sudo -E` to pass the environment of the user onto the command being run by sudo?